# Resistance 3, unable to delete game data, and installation of trophies freezing

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, resistance-3

Bought Resistance 3, popped it into the PS3 and the first thing that came up was an update. So I wait the 2 hours to download the 696 MB update, then let it install. The entire PS3 freezes at installing trophies. I cannot even get to XMB. I restart the PS3 manually and try to install again, same issue. So I try deleting the game data from XMB and it freezes the PS3. I manually restart again, and the game data now says "corrupted." I am unable to delete the corrupted data.

What do I do now?

Comment: Same thing happens to me. I am seriously debating seeing if the machine can fly.

Comment: Wow good question, I have no idea.  Have you entertained the idea of a HDD format?

Comment: Same happened to me!! This Ps3 machine is amateurish, why it cannot be deleted!! Bad joke! Resistance 3 is PS3 destroyer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually it worked after I kept deleting the corrupted data and retrying. Still disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me with Resistance 2 when I rented it; I just went back for a new game, which worked perfectly.

Try exchanging it for a new game. With your invoice, the majority of stores accept an exchange for a new copy.